# Pegando valores em String de ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Pego todos os meus valores do banco de dados e coloco em um `array list<object>` eu gostaria de saber como acessar o valor dentro desse emu arraylist, por exemplo `TesteLinhas.get(0).toString()` ou coisa do tipo me retorna aonde está alocado na memoria, creio eu. Eu gostaria que eu conseguisse o valor dela. Tem alguma forma?

```
ArrayList linhas = new ArrayList();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_zerados ORDER BY id ASC";

        conexao.pstm  = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        conexao.rs = conexao.pstm.executeQuery();

        while(conexao.rs.next()){
            linhas.add(new Object[]{conexao.rs.getInt("id"),
                                    conexao.rs.getInt("numero"),
                                    conexao.rs.getString("ano"),
                                    conexao.rs.getString("nome"),
                                    conexao.rs.getString("estilo"),
                                    conexao.rs.getString("plataforma"),
                                    conexao.rs.getInt("nota")});

        }

        System.out.println(linhas.get(1));
```

Ele me retorna isso: `[Ljava.lang.Object;@28a8f402`, sendo que eu gostaria que retornasse uma `String` ou um `Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada linha criada nessa lista é do tipo `array` de `Object[]`, quando for recuperar, tem que dar um `cast` do tipo (que no caso é `Object[]`)  e para recuperar as posições que no seu caso são **7** (de **0** a **6**) passar ao retorno a posição pretendida.

***Exemplo com todas as posições:***

```
System.out.println(((Object[])linhas.get(0))[0]);
System.out.println(((Object[])linhas.get(0))[1]);
System.out.println(((Object[])linhas.get(0))[2]);
System.out.println(((Object[])linhas.get(0))[3]);
System.out.println(((Object[])linhas.get(0))[4]);
System.out.println(((Object[])linhas.get(0))[5]);
System.out.println(((Object[])linhas.get(0))[6]);
```

[aqui tem um exemplo minimo](http://ideone.com/9RcKgv), com dados fictícios, mas, que podem te auxiliar a entender como tem que recuperar

Isso provavelmente vai solucionar o seu problema, mas, o ideal é sempre criar um dado `tipado` com um `array` usando esse ***tipo***, fica muito mais fácil a recuperação.

***Leitura:***

- [Explorando a Classe ArrayList no Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/explorando-a-classe-arraylist-no-java/24298)
- [Class ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [Java - The ArrayList Class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta me ajudou muito, parabéns por colaborar com a comunidade.

Comment: @HamonCórdova eu que agradeço. vlw

Answer (score 2):

Você está colocando um *array* dentro de um `ArrayList`. Não recomendo fazer desta forma, mas já que fez, a solução é acessar o elemento do *array* dentro do `ArrayList`. É como se fosse uma outra dimensão. Assim funciona:

```
System.out.println(linhas.get(1)[0]);
```

O `get(1)` está pegando a linha e o `[0]` está pegando a coluna.

Tem que fazer isto para cada campo, ou seja, deve ir do 0 até 6 já que tem 7 campos.

Pode fazer um laço:

```
for (Object obj : linhas.get(1)) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/GetElement.java).

Comment: Olá, ele me mandava erros, mas já consegui a solução com o outro que respondeu. Obrigado mesmo assim. Outra coisa, gostaria de saber o por que você quis dizer que é errado eu fazer assim? Fiz dessa forma pra preencher uma tabela usando um TableModel proprio.

Comment: É complicado responder em um comentário, basicamente você deveria ter uma classe para tratar disso e não jogar tudo em um *array*.

Answer (score 0):

Faço algo similar em meu aplicativo e isso pode te ajudar.

Tenho uma classe dbHelper, onde todos os metodos de manipulação do banco de dados são definidos.

Este é o método que lê o banco de dados e devolve uma lista (como um array) de objetos que refletem a tabela:

```
//Table Name
private static final String TABLE_RUNS = "runs";
//Table Columns
private static final String _ID = "_id";
private static final String COL_ADDRESS = "address"; 
private static final String COL_NAME = "name"; 
private static final String COL_DATE = "date"; 


List<RunData> getAllRuns() {

    List<RunData> runsList = new ArrayList<>();

    String RUN_SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RUNS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(RUN_SELECT_QUERY, null);

    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                RunData runData = new RunData();
                runData.run_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));

                runData.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME));
                runData.address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_RADDRESS));
                runData.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_DATE));

                runsList.add(runData);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to get posts from database");
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return runsList;
}
```

Use assim:

```
// Defina os objetos
RunDbHelper runDbHelper;
List<RunData> runList = new ArrayList<>();

// Instancie a classe dbHelper
runDbHelper = RunDbHelper.getInstance(getContext());
// call para ler o banco de dados e retornar uma lista de objetos runData
runList = runDbHelper.getAllRuns();
for (RunData runData : runList) { // percorre a lista de dados, usando runData como container
    // Agora, cada linha da lista (é manipulada como objeto de dados 
    doWhatwEver(runData.name, runData.address, runData.date); 
}
```

RunData é um objeto tipo POJO ou JavaBeans que tem os mesmos campos que a tabela. É mais fácil de manipular do que índices de um array.